# Query where values are less than equal

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have two documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2c7a84921716da1700b905"),
    "min" : 9000000,
    "name" : "One"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2b7848921716da1700b903"),
    "min" : 1400000,
    "name" : "Two"
}
```

So I want find only when the value of property `min` is less than equal to -for example-`8000000`.
With mongo I try with

```
db.collection.find({
    "min" : {
        $lte : 8000000
    }
})
```

But this returns two documents and no only one like in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM collection WHERE 8000000 <= collection.min;
```

How I can solved it?

P.S: I want says `8000000`

Comment: a>b and b<a are same thing  and your mogno query way is correct.

Comment: mongo is returning two docs because there are two documents with the size of key min is less than or equal to 12179800

Comment: @Astro I'm so sorry! I want says `8000000`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. In your SQL example, your condition is:

`WHERE 8000000 <= collection.min`

Now, let's swap the compared fields so that they match the order of your MongoDB query keeping the logic identical:

`WHERE collection.min >= 8000000`

You will notice that this query is effectively saying that `collection.min` must be *greater than* or equal to `8000000` - not smaller than or equal...

So your MongoDB query just needs to use the right operator:

```
db.collection.find({
    "min" : {
        $gte : 8000000
    }
})
```

Comment: Oh thanks too much. I Will try it this night. Thanks for you good answer!

Answer (score 1):

In mongoDB,you can can filter best like this:

```
db.collection.find()
.or([
     {$gte: 8000000}
   ])
```

Comment: since you can add more filters, it needs to be inside an array.